# Why ActionChains drag-and-drop (Selenium WD) dosent work with this script?

Tags: python, selenium

I made a script based on the [ActionChains documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html). But the picture does not move. Where is the mistake?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://parrot-tutorial.com/html/api_dragdrop.html")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='/images/parrot.png']")
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='box3']")

action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).click_and_hold()
action.move_to_element(element2).release()
action.perform()

time.sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `drag_and_drop` method provided by Selenium have you tried that? It would look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your.site.with.dragndrop.functionality.com")
source_element = driver.find_element_by_name('your element to drag')
dest_element = driver.find_element_by_name('element to drag to')
ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(source_element, dest_element).build().perform()
```

See the documentation [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#drag-and-drop)

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work. 
I think maybe something is wrong with the example on this site. https://parrot-tutorial.com/html/api_dragdrop.html

Comment: @J.Doe What if you add a .build() action right before perform()? I’ll edit that into my answer.

Comment: AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'build'

Comment: Ok don’t use build then. Looking at your current code for the action chains, I think you want every chain to finish with .perform().